# Access restriction to Notes.jar while developing Lotus Notes Plugin in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, lotus-notes, lotus, restriction

> Access restriction: The type Session is not accessible due to
>   restriction on required library C:\Program
>   Files\IBM\Lotus\Notes\jvm\lib\ext\Notes.jar

What am I missing? I tried to add Notes.jar explicitly. Also changed errors to warning. But I am still getting this compilation error. Also tried with admin mode.

How to remove this access restriction on library Notes.jar?

Comment: This might help: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd85forum.nsf/0/86AEA2CCE56EED0A852579570079AC4F?OpenDocument&ca=drs-fo

Comment: already tried this. error changed to warning is not a solution to the problem. suggest me more.

Answer (score 0):

If you add Notes.jar as a library, you can set "Access rules" for this library. You should add an "Accessible" rule "lotus/domino/*" for Notes.jar

Open the Libraries tab of the Java Build Path project property window

Expand the Notes.jar Library entry.

Select "Access rules" and hit the Edit button.

Click the Add button in the resulting dialog.

For the new access rule, set the resolution to Accessible and the pattern to "lotus/domino/**".

After adding this access rule, your project should build without these warning.